# Why isn't onCaptureOverlayStateChanged called for states other than "shown" and "stopped"?

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, google-api-client, google-play-developer-api

What I do is pretty straight forward. I have a class which implements `Videos.CaptureOverlayStateListener`. When the Google API client is connected, I call `Games.Videos.registerCaptureOverlayStateChangedListener` for this class. Then I have a simple log call inside its `onCaptureOverlayStateChanged` method.

Then I manually show the capture overlay like this:

```
public void showRecordingOverlay() {
    Intent intent = Games.Videos.getCaptureOverlayIntent(this.apiClient);
    this.activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 777);
}
```

... and record a short video.

`onCaptureOverlayStateChanged` gets called only with `CAPTURE_OVERLAY_STATE_SHOWN` and `CAPTURE_OVERLAY_STATE_CAPTURE_STOPPED`.

Even though I (obviously) start the video recording and eventually close the overlay (by dragging it to the X in the center of the screen), `CAPTURE_OVERLAY_STATE_CAPTURE_STARTED` and `CAPTURE_OVERLAY_STATE_DISMISSED` never seem to be sent.

So... why does this happen? Do I need to do something special for these notifications?

Comment: We're having the same issues.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer this this?

Comment: Nope. I've put it on hold for now. I have absolutely no idea how to proceed :)

Comment: Thanks for the response :) Keep us posted, will do the same